# Animation from edittext to listview row in android

Tags: android, performance, listview, animation, android-listview

I am working on animation in android and got stuck when try to do this animation.

I have an edittext and listview. User type message in edittext and press Ok. The message written in edittext is appended in listview. I want to translate the message from edittext to the position where it is going to attach in listView.

I am using this animation in getView method of listview. I am only doing animation on last item of listview when it is adding in listView

```
<translate
android:fromXDelta="-80%" android:toXDelta="0%"
android:fromYDelta="2000%" android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration="800" />
```

**getView method animation code**

//shouldAnimate is true only when getView is called during messageAdding in listView

```
    if(position == getCount() -1 && shouldAnimate) {
    v.startAnimation(animation);
    shouldAnimate = false;
}
```

I think it can to be done by translate animation where it's source and destination position changes for different views. I am not sure show to calculate initial and final coordinates for translate animation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to add a OnPreDrawListener? And are you willing to use objectAnimator?

Comment: Is this question still active?